# How to determine if I clicked on the content in a tag <p>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some html markup:

```
<div id="content">
    <h3>blablalba</h3>
    <p>paragraph1</p>                                 
    <p>paragraph2</p>
    <p>paragraph3</p>
    <h3>blablabla</h3>
    <p>paragraph4</p>
    <p>paragraph5</p>
    <p>paragraph6</p>
</div>
```

And a function to highlight all the tags (important: I need to highlight all the tags) and the class where I need to know if it is a paragraph.

```
function myClass (input) {
    this.input = input;
    //on init
    init = function() {
        alert(input); //Point to determine if it is a paragraph
    };
    init();
};

$(function() {
    $("#content *").hover( function () {
        $(this).css("border", "1px solid blue");    //  style to mark (highlight) the tag
        return false;
    },
    function () {
        $(this).css("border", "none");  //  unmark the tag
    }).click( function () {
            var inst = new myClass($(this).html());
    });
});
```

How can I find if I clicked on the paragraph, not on the other tags.

Sample http://jsfiddle.net/rvvbf4L1/1/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
$(function () {
    $("#content *").hover(function () {
        $(this).css("border", "1px solid blue"); // style to mark (highlight) the paragraph
        return false;
    },

    function () {
        $(this).css("border", "none"); //   unmark the paragraphs
    }).click(function (e) {
        var inst = new myClass(e.target.nodeName);
    });
});
```

The change I made is `var inst = new myClass(e.target.nodeName);`

[Reference](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rvvbf4L1/5/)

Comment: I need to highlight all tags.

Comment: It will be helpful for others also

Answer (score 2):

Within your click handler you can simply use `$(this).is('p')` to test if the element clicked on is a paragraph or not.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rvvbf4L1/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

When an event occurs, an event object is created. From that event object, you can get some extra info. For example, you can get the target element clicked.

```
$('.selector').click(function(evtObj){
    if (evtObj.target.tagName === "P"){ // note the capital P
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution: http://jsfiddle.net/1c1nr9sp/5/

```
$('p').on('click', function(){
    console.log('clicked on a paragraph');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is what you want, but here you go!:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = 'es'>
    <head>
        <title> My Test </title>
        <style>
                p:hover{
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <h3>Title</h3>
                <p>paragraph1</p>                                 
                <p>paragraph2</p>
                <p>paragraph3</p>
            <h3>Title</h3>
                <p>paragraph4</p>
                <p>paragraph5</p>
                <p>paragraph6</p>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var tagList = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
            var index;

            for(index in tagList){
                tagList[index].addEventListener('click', consoleMessage);
            }

            function consoleMessage(){
                console.log('Clicked on a paragraph');
                alert('Clicked on a paragraph');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```